# NPM 'prestart' script equivalent in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

In a `package.json` file (which is basically the Node version of Flutters `pubspec.yaml`) You have a `scripts` section where you can add your own custom scripts. Normally with a node project you'll have a `start` script that will kick off the build and, well, start the project. In flutter you have `flutter run`.

In my flutter project I'm using the `json_serializabl`e package that generates the code that I use when serialising my objects to JSON. Right now I have to have two terminal windows open:

**Tab 1**

Runs `flutter packages pub run build_runner watch` that does the code generation and watches the file system.

**Tab 2**

Run `flutter run` that runs the project with hot reloading.

So it would be great if you had something like Nodes `prestart` in `pubspec.yaml` where I can run the code generation automatically when I run `flutter run`

Comment: There currently is no such thing in Dart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There currently is no such thing in Dart. You can create your own Dart or shell scripts in `tool/` that runs your builder_runner command detached (in the background) and the `flutter run` command in the foreground.
you can start this just using `tool/run.dart`

However with `build` becoming mature and `pub serve`/`pub build` being deprecated I assume the Dart team is thinking already about making this a more pleasant experience.

Comment: `pub serve/build` are deprecated ?

Comment: Right. It won't be included in Dart 2 final. `build` and associated packages are the replacement. https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/announce/R4kV3us0Sm8